# Participar de ou participar em?

Tags: português-brasileiro

Falamos **participar de** ou **participar em**?

> Exemplo: Lemantamos que vocês não possam participar de evento.

Nos maiorias casos que eu vi, a forma certa está **participar de**. Existe alguns casos com **participar em**?

Ou seja, posso falar assim?

> Lemantamos que vocês não possam *participar em* evento.

Comment: Uma breve busca na infopedia daria a resposta https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/participar
Esta pergunta pode ser fechada por falta de pesquisa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Os dois estão certos:  no português do participar com o significado de «tomar parte em», «compartilhar», «ter parte em» e «partilhar» é manifesta a opção pela uso da preposição de. O "em" é mais usado no português de Portugual.

Comment: Além de confusa, a resposta ainda está possivelmente errada. Há diferença semântica entre 'participar de' e 'participar em'.

Comment: @William, para mim, o problema é a falta de uso de boa prática de português e a falta de fontes. Se referenciasse a um dicionário, já seria suficiente.